# Add Suffix To All Internal URLs

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to add a suffix of ?hl=foo to the end of all internal URLs on my site.

Im not sure of the best way to do this because of complications such as...

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">My Site</a>
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com">My Site</a>
<a class="a-class" href="http://www.example.com">My Site</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP

Just create a variable that you echo in the source.

Example:

```
<?php $my_get = "?hl=foo"; ?>

<a href="http://mysite.com<?=$my_get?>"> Yadda </a>
```

Using Javascript to change each **a**'s *href* attribute:

1. Obtain all the  elements ( getElementsByTagName('a') )
2. Run a foreach loop on them
3. Within the foreach, concat the existing href (http://mysite.com) and ?hl=f00

Comment: I can't do that due to complications with the CMS I'm using. However I can run PHP after the CMS has done it's bit. Such as preg_replace.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`output_add_rewrite_var` function](http://docs.php.net/output_add_rewrite_var):

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    output_add_rewrite_var('hl', 'foo');
?>
<a href="/">My Site</a>
<a target="_blank" href="/">My Site</a>
<a class="a-class" href="/">My Site</a>
```

But I don’t think it works with absolute URLs.